# Is message deduplication essential on the Kafka consumer side?

Tags: apache-kafka, duplicates, kafka-producer-api, payment-processing

Kafka [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) states the following as the top scenario:

> To process **payments and financial** transactions in real-time, such as
> in stock exchanges, banks, and insurances

Also, regarding the main concepts, right at the very top:

> Kafka provides various guarantees such as the ability to process
> events **exactly-once**.

It’s funny the document says:

> Many systems claim to provide "exactly once" delivery semantics, but
> it is important to read the fine print, most of these **claims are
> misleading**…

It seems obvious that payments/financial transactions must be processed „exactly-once“, but the rest of Kafka documentation doesn't make it obvious how this should be accomplished.
Let’s focus on the producer/publisher side:

> If a producer attempts to publish a message and experiences a network
> error it cannot be sure if this error happened before or after the
> message was committed. This is similar to the semantics of inserting
> into a database table with an autogenerated key. … Since 0.11.0.0, the
> Kafka producer also supports an idempotent delivery option which
> **guarantees that resending will not result in duplicate entries** in the
> log.

KafkaProducer only ensures that it doesn’t incorrectly resubmit messages (resulting in duplicates) itself. Kafka cannot cover the case where client app code crashes (along with KafkaProducer) and it is not sure if it previously invoked send (or commitTransaction in case of transactional producer) which means that application-level retry will result in duplicate processing.

> Exactly-once delivery for other destination systems generally
> requires cooperation with such systems, but Kafka provides the offset
> which makes implementing this feasible (see also Kafka Connect).

The above statement is only partially correct, meaning that while it exposes offsets on the Consumer side, it doesn’t make exactly-once feasible at all on the producer side.

Kafka consume-process-produce loop enables exactly-once processing leveraging sendOffsetsToTransaction, but again cannot cover the case of the possibility of duplicates on the first producer in the chain.

The provided official [demo for EOS](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.5/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples) (Exactly once semantics) only provides an example for consume-process-produce EOS.

Solutions involving DB transaction log readers which read already committed transactions, also cannot be sure if they will produce duplicate messages in case they crash.

There is no support for a distributed transaction (XA) involving a database and the Kafka producer.

---

Does all of this mean that in order to ensure exactly once processing for payments and financial transactions (Kafka top use case!), **we absolutely must perform business-level message deduplication on the consumer side**, inspite of the Kafka transport-level “guarantees”/claims?

Note: I’m aware of:
[Kafka Idempotent producer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739260/kafka-idempotent-producer)
but I would like a clear answer if deduplication is inevitable on the consumer side.

Comment: Please limit your posts to single questions or specific problems, and you linked to the wrong demo https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.5/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples/KafkaExactlyOnceDemo.java

Comment: Thanks for the interest! 
Do you propose I remove all the "is it correct" and "official example" questions so only the final one remains?
I linked to the demo composed of only 1 consumer and 1 producer because I'm interested in end-to-end EOS. The demo, which you propose, demonstrates consume-process-produce where an ExactlyOnceMessageProcessor has been inserted in between the consumer and the producer. This demo again doesn't demonstrate how the producer side duplication should be prevented, so it doesn't help answering specifically if we must perform deduplication on the consumer side.

Comment: The transaction support is internal to the client, plus its exactly once _per batch_, to the best of my knowledge. If you must prevent duplicates over the whole app lifecycle, across restarts, Kafka cannot control that. I recall a previous project where financial teams used Mongo or Hbase, I think, to perform two-phase commits without duplicates against Kafka

Comment: And the linked demo is just a regular consumer and producer, no transaction

Comment: I'd be very interested to hear more about "two-phase commits without duplicates against Kafka". I still don't understand this advertisement for "exactly-once" for payment systems - when it seems Kafka alone cannot guarantee this.

Comment: I don't have any details more than that since I wasn't on that team, but I do know they used Kafka for handling millions of dollars worth of travel bookings for a large company... In any case, multiple blogs have been written about how the transaction and EOS features of Kafka work outside of the official documentation - https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/ and more written on 2PC that aren't related to Kafka operations

Comment: The meaning of the  kafka documentation on "Exactly once" processing different stages like Producer, consumer, business logic in side consumer. Ex : The message infra delivers exactly once but the business logic in consumer may process it twice becoz of some issue or becoz of legitimate reason.

Comment: Not sure how to proceed. Would prefer we don't turn this into a discussion through comments. Please provide the answer if you consider the question to be clear now.

Comment: The simple answer is "yes" because Kafka doesn't know your business logic for consumer processing. In other words, an individual event can be sent/processed "exactly once", **but** if you copy the exact same data into a producer, send it again, that's a **unique** offset/event that the consumer would have to detect/ignore, so  you'd ideally prevent duplicates on both sides of the topic

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer :) All that I've read confirms this, so please make your comment into an answer (or explain if you think this question doesn't warrant an answer).
Internally, I expect KafkaProducer does its job fine. But if the same message gets sent twice by producer app, no amount of offset handling on the consumer side will be enough – only application deduplication will ensure it gets processed “exactly-once”. It’s like speaking about the "secure" house, all windows and backdoors locked, but, hey the front door is actually a curtain.

Answer (score 1):

You must deduplicate on consumer side since rebalance on consumer side can really cause processing of events more than once in a consumer group based on fetch size and commit interval parameters.

If a consumer exits without acknowledging back to broker, Kafka will assign those events to another consumer in the group. Example if you are pulling a batch size of 5 events, if consumer dies or goes for a restart after processing first 3(If the external api/db fails OR the worse case your server runs out of memory and crashes), the current consumer dies abruptly without making a commit back/ack to broker. Hence the same batch gets assigned to another consumer from group(rebalance) where it starts supplies the same event batch again which will result in re-processing of same set of records resulting in duplication. A good read here : https://quarkus.io/blog/kafka-commit-strategies/

You can make use of internal state store of Kafka for deduplication. Here there is no offset/partition tracking, its kind of cache(persistent time bound on cluster).

In my case we push correlationId(a unique business identifier in incoming event) into it on successful processing of events, and all new events are checked against this before processing to make sure its not a duplicate event. Enabling state store will create more internal topics in Kafka cluster, just an FYI.

https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#state-stores

Comment: Interesting - while I was expecting that the cause for duplicates might be because of the producer side design, you point that even the consumer side can cause duplicate processing. Could you provide a reference for the statement in the first paragraph / edit the answer?

Comment: updated answer.